# Python, TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument. Only When using ThreadPoolExcecutor's submit function

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

It looks like I'm doing something funky when using  ThreadPoolExcecutor's submit()  & cant figure it out.

**Some dummy class used demonstrate the issue:**

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def returnSomething(self,param1,param2):
        counter = 0 
        while (counter<100):
            counter = counter + 1
        return param1+param2
```

**Synchronous simple mock:**

```
val=TestClass().returnSomething("a","b")
print(val)
```

**All is good.**

**NOW THE PROBLEM, when attempting to use ThreadPoolExecutor's submit():**

GlobalValues.py (relevant snippet only):

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class GlobalValues(object):
    #singleton thread pool 
    Executor : ThreadPoolExecutor = None
    @staticmethod
    def getThreadPoolExecutor():
        if GlobalValues.Executor==None:
            GlobalValues.Executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(500)
        return GlobalValues.Executor
```

**Attempted asynchronous call:**

```
testClass = TestClass()
    async_result=GlobalValues.getThreadPoolExecutor().submit(testClass.returnSomething,(TestClass,"a","b"))
    val = async_result.result()
```

**Then I suddenly get:**

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: returnSomething() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param2'
```

How can I resolve the missing parameter issue (Note, "self" is not parameter that should be passed so dont reply with pass in (self,param2,param2)?

Appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct function signature no need for parenthesis or class name:

```
async_result=GlobalValues.getThreadPoolExecutor().submit(testClass.returnSomething,param1="ac",param2="bc")
```

Works as expected:

```
root@DESKTOP-82J6K7V:~/trade# python3 test_main.py 
acbc
```

Answer (score 0):

`submit`'s type signature is `(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)).

Therefore, you have to pass the callback followed by its parameters for them to match against `*args` (you should not create a tuple yourself - the interpreter will convert the extra parameters into a tuple when matching the `*args` syntax).

In your case you want to pass a ([bound](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=bound)) method as the callback - a non-static member of a class, that is "bounded" to it's `self` value - therefore you do not need to supply the class as a paratmeter, and the following will work:

```
async_result = GlobalValues.getThreadPoolExecutor().submit(
    testClass.returnSomething, "a", "b"
)
```

Alternatively, if you want to pass the unbound method as the callback, the following will also work (and supply the `self` parameter on the function invocation by the executor):

```
async_result = GlobalValues.getThreadPoolExecutor().submit(
    TestClass.returnSomething, testClass, "a", "b"
)
```